# Cannot add a new item in sitecore content tree

Tags: sitecore

I have this issue with sitecore that started happening recently. Whenever i try to add a new item using a template, I get the following error. Could someone help me why this is happening.

**Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.AddFromTemplate.SelectItem (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).**

Stack Trace:

```
[Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.AddFromTemplate.SelectItem (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +138
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +428
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +67
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +141
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Processor.Parse(XmlNode node) +401
   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineFactory.GetProcessors(String pipelineName) +376
   Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineFactory.GetPipeline(String pipelineName) +74
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Start(String processor, NameValueCollection parameters) +94
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Items.Start(String pipelineName, Item item) +273
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, CommandContext context) +193
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.HandleMessage(Message message) +1874
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +168
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +612
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

Comment: It looks like somehow `Sitecore.Buckets.dll` was removed from your web application `bin` folder. Check if it's there and if not, copy it from the vanilla Sitecore.zip. Remember to use same Sitecore version your app uses.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is with the version of the dll. It got changed somehow.

Comment: Use Sitecore's new NuGet server in visual studio. Then no one needs a lib folder with the chance of the dlls being wrong. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq